# WheelView (extends ListView) blinks when apply setSelection

Tags: android, widget

I have a problem with WheelView (extends ListView) using [this library](https://github.com/venshine/WheelView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3853). When I apply .setSelection(i) (or .selection = i) the WheelView blinks. Is there a workaround to avoid the blinking? For example the function .getWheelData (which update the WheelView with new data) does not lead to a blinking WheelView.

Comment: how is it related to `wxWidgets`?

Comment: sorry, wrong tag.